# Adding objects to List

Tags: java, list

It could be a very simple solution but I just started learning Java. I would like to add every instantiated Product to the productList. Is there any way to solve this problem without modifying the access modifiers?

```
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float defaultPrice;
    private Currency defaultCurrency;
    private Supplier supplier;
    private static List<Product> productList;
    private ProductCategory productCategory;

    public Product(float defaultPrice, Currency defaultCurrency, String name) {
        this.id = IdGenerator.createID();
        this.defaultPrice = defaultPrice;
        this.defaultCurrency = defaultCurrency;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `Product` containing a list of `Product`s as a variable on class level (`static`)?

Comment: From a design point of view using static lists in the way you do is normally something you shouldn't do but I'll leave that for now. If `productList` is initialized (if not you could add `=new LinkedList<>()` to the declaration) you could just do `productList.add(this)` in the constructor.

Comment: Just delete the static list. it's a bad idea in the real world and doesn't teach you anything either.

Comment: If you are modeling something like a manufacturing company, then you would need something like an `Inventory` class. In *that* class you would have a list of `Product`. Each `Product` would *not* have list of nested `Product`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a newly created `Product` to the list in its constructor:

```
public class Product {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float defaultPrice;
    private Currency defaultCurrency;
    private Supplier supplier;
    private static List<Product> productList = new LinkedList<>();
    private ProductCategory productCategory;

    public Product(float defaultPrice, Currency defaultCurrency, String name){
        this.id = IdGenerator.createID();
        this.defaultPrice = defaultPrice;
        this.defaultCurrency = defaultCurrency;
        this.name = name;
        productList.add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works, having a mutable `static` collection should be avoided wherever possible +1

Answer (score 1):

Change the initialisation line

`private static List<Product> productList;`

to

`private static List<Product> productList = new LinkedList<>();`

Add `productList.add(this)` as the last line of the constructor.

So each time you call the Product constructor, it will add this instance to the static list.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey) mentionned it in the comment section of [Mureinik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223841/4391450), having a `static` collection in the POJO is not the best solution.

I would suggest to use a simple facade. This limit the list existence to the facade life and don't include the logic of a collection in a POJO.

```
public class FacadeProduct {

    private List<Product> cacheProduct = new ArrayList<>();

    public Product createProduct(float defaultPrice, Currency defaultCurrency, String name){
        Product p = new Product(defaultPrice, defaultCurrency, name);
        cacheProduct.add(p);
        return p;
    }
}
```

This would be quite simple to use.

```
public static void main(String ars[]){
    {
        FacadeProduct f = new FacadeProduct();
        {
            Product p1 = f.createProduct(1f, null, "test1");
            Product p2 = f.createProduct(1f, null, "test2");
            Product p3 = f.createProduct(1f, null, "test3");
            // Here, the list have 3 instances in it
        }
        // We lose the p1, p2, p3 reference, but the list is still holding them with f.
    }
    //Here, we lose the f reference, the instances are all susceptible to be collected by the GC. Cleaning the memory
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize productList with null, and then modify the constructor as follows:

```
public Product(float defaultPrice, Currency defaultCurrency, String name) {
        this.id = IdGenerator.createID();
        this.defaultPrice = defaultPrice;
        this.defaultCurrency = defaultCurrency;
        this.name = name;
        if (productList == null) productList = new ArrayList<>();
        productList.add(this);
    }
```